# Find most frequent line in file in bash

Tags: bash, lines

Suppose I have a file similar to as follows:

```
Abigail 85
Kaylee 25
Kaylee 25
kaylee
Brooklyn
Kaylee 25
kaylee 25
```

I would like to find the most repeated line, the output must be just the line.

I've tried

```
sort list | uniq -c
```

but I need clean output, just the most repeated line (in this example `Kaylee 25`).

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/383726/get-the-most-common-appearing-lines-from-file-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kaizen ~

```
$ sort zlist | uniq -c | sort -r | head -1|  xargs | cut -d" " -f2-

Kaylee 25
```

does this help ?

Comment: I don't think the call to `xargs` is necessary here.

Comment: xargs .... its to supress the spaces , its plain and simple . you could also use translate if you liked !!

Comment: `xargs` will suppress valid consecutive spaces as well. You'll probably need to remove `xargs` and use some other method like `sed s/^\s\+[0-9]\+\s//'` to remove the count column instead of `cut`

Comment: Use `sort --version-sort` instead of `sort -r`. For example, `--version-sort` will properly output "351, 51, 5", while `-r` will output "5, 351, 51".

Comment: Note that this solution is wrong because the second `sort` doesn't have `-n` (pointed out by the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229009/))

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, none of these answers will sort the results correctly. The reason is that sort, without the `-n`, option will sort like this "`1 10 11 2 3 4`", etc., instead of "`1 2 3 4 10 11 12`". So, add `-n` like so:

```
sort zlist | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -1
```

You can then, of course, pipe that to either xargs or sed  as described earlier.

Answer (score 2):

awk -

```
awk '{a[$0]++; if(m<a[$0]){ m=a[$0];s[m]=$0}} END{print s[m]}' t.lis
```

Comment: Interesting and different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ uniq -c list | sort -r | head -1 | awk '{$1=""}1'

Kaylee 25
```

Is this what you're looking for?