# Find the most common line in a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I have a file of strings:

```
string-string-123
string-string-123
string-string-123
string-string-12345
string-string-12345
string-string-12345-123
```

How do I retrieve the most common line in bash (`string-string-123`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find most frequent line in file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922357/find-most-frequent-line-in-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use awk to do this:

```
awk '{++a[$0]}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]>max){max=a[i];k=i}print k}' file
```

The array `a` keeps a count of each line. Once the file has been read, we loop through it and find the line with the maximum count.

Alternatively, you can skip the loop in the `END` block by assigning the line during the processing of the file:

```
awk 'max < ++c[$0] {max = c[$0]; line = $0} END {print line}' file
```

Thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for this useful suggestion.

---

It has rightly been pointed out that the two approaches above will only print out one of the most frequently occurring lines in the case of a tie. The following version will print out all of the most frequently occurring lines:

```
awk 'max<++c[$0] {max=c[$0]} END {for(i in c)if(c[i]==max)print i}' file
```

Comment: Move the "max" logic out of the END block for simiplicity: `awk '{if (max < ++c[$0]) {max = c[$0]; line = $0}} END {print line}'`

Comment: That's an elegant solution, but note that if there are _ties_ for the most frequently occurring line, your solution will only print _one_ of them, and it won't be obvious which.

Comment: @mklement0 it's a fair point. I've added another version which prints all of them.

Comment: Thanks for updating - nicely done. The only remaining concern is that this approach may not work with large input files, given that you read _all distinct_ input lines into memory, which could be a problem with a large number of distinct lines in the input. On the plus side, your approach is _much faster_ than the `sort` / `uniq` approach.

Comment: Another way is to use asort `awk '{b[a[$0]++]=$0}END{asort(b);print b[1]}'`

Answer (score 21):

You can use `sort` with `uniq`

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

Answer (score 5):

- [Tom Fenech's elegant `awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321064/45375) works great [in the amended version that prints *all* most frequently occurring lines in the event of a tie].
  However, it may not be suitable for large files, because all *distinct* input lines are stored in an associative array in memory, which could be a problem if there are many non-duplicate lines; that said, it's much *faster* than the approaches discussed below.
- [Grzegorz Żur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321075/45375) combines multiple utilities elegantly to *implicitly* produce the desired result, but:

  - *all* distinct lines are printed (highest-frequency count first)
  - output lines are *prefixed by their occurrence count* (which may actually be desirable).

While you can pipe [Grzegorz Żur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321075/45375) to `head` to limit the number of lines shown, you can't assume a *fixed* number of lines in general.

Building on Grzegorz's answer, here's a generic **solution that shows *all* most-frequently-occurring lines - however many there are - and *only* them**:

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -n -r | awk 'NR==1 {prev=$1} $1!=prev {exit} 1'
```

If you don't want the output lines prefixed with the occurrence count:

```
sort file | uniq -c | sort -n -r | awk 'NR==1 {prev=$1} $1!=prev {exit} 1' | 
  sed 's/^ *[0-9]\{1,\} //'
```

---

Explanation of [Grzegorz Żur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321075/45375):

- `uniq -c` outputs the set of *unique* input lines *prefixed with their respective occurrence count* (`-c`), followed by a single space.
- `sort -n -r` then sorts the resulting lines numerically (`-n`), in descending order (`-r`), so that the most frequently occurring line(s) are at the top.

  - Note that `sort`, if `-k` is not specified, will generally try to sort by the *entire* input line, but `-n` causes only the *longest prefix that is recognized as an integer* to be used for sorting, which is exactly what's needed here.

---

Explanation of my `awk` command:

- `NR==1 {prev=$1}` stores the 1st whitespace-separated field (`$1`) in variable `prev` for the *first* input line (`NR==1`)
- `$1!=prev {exit}` terminates processing, if the 1st whitespace-separated field is not the same as the previous line's - this means that a non-topmost line has been reached, and no more lines need printing.
- `1` is shorthand for `{ print }` meaning that the input line at hand should be printed as is.

---

Explanation of my `sed` command:

- `^ *[0-9]\{1,\}` matches the numeric prefix (denoting the occurrence count) of each output line, as (originally) produced by `uniq -c`
- applying `s/...//` means that the prefix is replaced with an *empty string*, i.e., effectively *removed*.